# Does anybody know how to have dots from the equation to the equation label?

Tags: cross-referencing

I've been attempting to get a row of dots from the end of the equation right to the equation label, that allows the reader to easily trace along from, say, an equation on the right of the page, muuch like the format commonly used for contents pages; headings with a row of dots leading to the page number(s) so that the reader doesn't get lost, trying to trace along the "line" with no guide per se.

Thanks

Comment: Alternatively, you could add colored lines with tikz and tikzmark.